# How to change the colour of an entire uiimage

Tags: image-processing, uiimage

I have a UIImage containing a pattern in the center, and the rest of the image is transparent. it's a png file and the pattern is of only one colour. I have created a table from which users can pick a colour (a UIColor), and I want to change the colour of the pattern to the one picked by user. I know how to change the colour for a pixel within an image, but is there any way of changing the colour of the entire pattern, or do I have to change every pixel one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across another topic here, which I don't remember what it was called!!:( but in case, if you look for image colour manipulation, you'll find it:)

Answer (score 1):

Enter the image and the colour you want to change it to into the method below. Will return you a freshly coloured image based on the outline.

```
-(UIImage *)returnImage:(UIImage *)image coloured:(UIColor *)colour {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, colour.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;

}
```